# How can I make the menu items flash, like on MacOS, when clicked in Compiz

Tags: compiz, menu, gnome-flashback

In Gnome Flashback (Compiz), how can I make the menu buttons flash once with the highlight colour when clicked, before the menu disappears? This'd be useful in emulating MacOS/OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this via the window manager (compiz) really. It could be done in a widget theme engine (I am not sure if it is possible with only CSS in a theme at this point). The window manager doesn't have any knowledge about the internal contents of the window (menu), so it wouldn't know which section of the window to blink. In a theme, you can override the drawing of each individual menu item in the menu, though.

A theme engine would require writing C code. If it's possible with just CSS in a GTK+ theme, it could be done that way, however. Note that this would only really work in applications using the GTK+ tool kit, too, not in all applications (though for applications which have their main menus show up in the titlebar or top panel, it should work there, just not for app-internal menus in all those cases).